# how to use javascript global variable in google chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

i have define variable globally in java script and want to use it in google chart, but it giving undefined error.

```
  var period;
$(document).ready(function () {

 $('#period').on('change', function () {
    window.period = this.value;
    alert(period);
   });
    // period variable in google chart is showing undefined
      google.charts.load('current', {
    callback: function drawChart() {
     var jsonData = $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "{{ url('/datesalesbarchartdata') }}/" + period ,
            dataType: "json",
            global: false,
            async: false,
            success: function (jsondata) {

            }
        }).responseText;
```

Comment: Might the whole code be inside some other IIFE? Try assigning to just `period`, or refer to `window.period` inside `drawChart` (also, are you sure the chart starts being loaded *after* period is first defined?)

Comment: Remove the var from in front of 'period'

Comment: @Difster Noooo!

Comment: Sure @Teemu - Check it out: https://jsfiddle.net/difster/ybku12q9/1/

Comment: @CertainPerformance it works when i insert `drawChart` in `period` below i will share working code.Thanks You all for your help.

Comment: @Difster Using undeclared variables is like you'd hit your head with a hammer ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working code

```
     var period;
    $('#period').on('change', function () {
    window.period = this.value;

google.charts.load('current', {
    callback: function drawChart() {
        console.log(period);
       var jsonData = $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "{{ url('/datesalesbarchartdata') }}/" + period ,
            dataType: "json",
            global: false,
            async: false,
            success: function (jsondata) {

            }
        }).responseText;
      });
```